# how to trigger animation of a model by touching it in UNITY 5.5

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm new to UNITY. Its a simple question but I'm not able to do this...
I have model in my scene with animation and animator. The default state of model is IDLE. I want it to go to Moving State when I touch that MODEL on my Mobile screen. 
I'm able to animate this when i touch anywhere on screen ... But I want it to **play "moving" animation when I touch that particular 3D Object/Model in scene.** Here is my Code :

```
void Start () {
    ani = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
void Update() {
//FOR MOUSE
//if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
//      Debug.Log ("mouse button was pressed");
//      ani.Play ("moving",-1,0f);
//FOR MOBILE
  if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        ani.Play ("moving", -1, 0f);        
    }
```

I attached this script on Model.  I tried out diffrent method but nothing is working:

```
 //NOT WORKING
    //if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    //      {
    //          Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    //          RaycastHit hit;
    //
    //          if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    //          {
    //              ani = hit.collider.GetComponent<Animator>();
    //              ani.Play("moving",-1,0f);
    //          }
```

AND

```
// NOT WORKING
//if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
//      {
//          RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Input.GetTouch(0).position)), Vector2.zero);
//          if(hit.collider != null)
//          {
//              Debug.Log ("Touched it");
//              ani.Play ("moving", -1, 0f);
//          }
//  }
```

I know this is small code ...please tell me where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Go to **5.For 3D Object (Mesh Renderer/any 3D Collider)** on the duplicated answer. Don't forget to attach collider to your model.

Comment: box collider works but mesh collider not

Comment: This is not true. A collider is always a collider. It doesn't matter if Mesh or Box Collider. This works on any collider. If you have a problem, create new question but provide your code that doesn't work. Also, provide a screenshot that shows the collider settings of the object you want to detect click on. You are definitely doing something wrong!

Comment: `foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
  {
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
   //Debug.Log("RAY:" + ray.direction);
   if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
   {
    Debug.Log("touched");
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
    {
     Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.green);
     Debug.Log("Ray touched " + hit.transform.name);
     nam = hit.transform.name;
     ani.Play ("moving", -1, 0f);
    }`
working fine with box/sphere collider bot not with mesh

Comment: The code you have has nothing to do with the code in the answer from the duplicated question. I did not perform any raycast. This will be my last reply to this post. You can ask a new question with the correct code. If you use that code in your above comment for your new question, I will likely  close that new question too. Read that post! Read from **5.For 3D Object (Mesh Renderer/any 3D Collider)**